# Crontab bash script: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, cron

A bash script is executed with crontab. For each run the following error is delivered as email:

```
/opt/Informatica/pcdev/scripts/startworkflow_trg.sh: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Content in the crontab is as follows:

```
# Check queue and start corresponding processes in test
* * * * * (. ~/.bash_profile; $HOME/scripts/startworkflow_trg.sh tst)
```

The script works as it should, but the error emails are piling up in the inbox. How can this error be solved?

Comment: Do you receive the same error message when running the script manually?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $HOME` ?

Comment: Change `~` to `$HOME` and remove the unnecessary parentheses and replace the semi-colon with `&&`.

Comment: How do you call the script out of the cron context ?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio at first I thought it is a problem with the crontab configuration, but now I noticed that the error also appears while running the script manually.

Comment: @ph3nx That changes the situation! In such case, you may want to update your question and adding your script content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the line in the script where the error occurs different parts of the script were commented out. The problem occured even when there was only the first line left, containing:
`#!/bin/bash`

The problem was solved by creating a new script and writing the first line from above manually and pasting the remaining content of the old script. We think there were characters in the first line of the script that were not visible in our editor.

Answer (score 8):

The issue occurs when copying and pasting lines between Windows and Linux when doing a `crontab -e`.

The Windows `LF` char `x'0d'` gets inserted and causes issues. The solution is to remove all lines and type them back in.   You can spot the issue by doing a `crontab -l | od -x` and looking for the `0d` characters.

Comment: This is so hard to find, thank you very much!